# angularJS - webapp architecture

Tags: angularjs, architecture

I have to build an angularJS webapp and found many resource for best practice but there are still some questions that were not answered. I hope you can help me.

**Question 1: Model**

One thing is, where should i store my model and handle changes to it? 
I found some different solutions but they were all for simple datastructures. I have something like User ---> Subscription ---> Device ---> HardwareReport. And this is just one branch of the datastructure tree.
My question is where should i store it so that every Controller can access the data.

**Current solution:**

Current solution would be, not to store the data structure but to have a service for every object type like *UserService* or *SubscriptionService*.
And every of these services handles the communication with the backend server and keeps the return value in a cache.

**Downside:** 
If a controller needs for example all devices of the user it has to deal with all services and can't just go through the data-structure tree. What if one controller changes for example the device object of the user. How should i notify other controllers?

**Question 2: lazy configure/instantiate services**

Here is a part of the application.

I have an *AppController*, *LoginController* and a *MapController*.

And i have a *BackendService* which encapsulates the API-Calls and is used by *UserService* and *SubscriptionService*.

When i login into my webapp the *LoginController* uses the *SessionService* to verify the login data and receives an accessToken for the API.
This accessToken must be set in the *BackendService* to be added to the header.
But the BackendService is already injected in other services.

**Current solution:**
Just set the AccessToken from LoginController like

```
BackendService.setAuth(accessToken);
```

Because the service is singleton all other services that uses *BackendService* will be have the correct setup *BackendService*.

**Downside:**
I can call functions of the *BackendService* before setting the access token and this would result in errors.

** Alternative solution: **
I just implement a *BackendServiceFactory* which i can use at any time to create a new BackendService instance. So i can create the *BackendService* in the LoginController after login.

**Downside:** I have to pass this object through all my services and controller because it won't be injected by DI.

Quite long questions but i hope you can give me some suggestions how to build this app.